# How to extend expiry of a long-live token in facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-access-token

I am having a issue here, I have a long-live access token, I dont want this token to expire after 60 days, I Understand that to extend the life time  of a long-live token we need to fire a query below using shot-live token..

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
   grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
   client_id={app-id}&
   client_secret={app-secret}&
   fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

But  short lived token expires in hours .. So i cant use the same short-live token again to request for extending life span of long-live token . Is there any way i can do it programaticaly, I dont want user to come in picture any time once he has created short-lived token in the beggining... any help is appreciated..

Regards
Sunil

Comment: You can not exchange a long-lived token for a new one – you have to get a new short-lived one from the user. The system is explicitly _designed_ this way.

Comment: so can i atleast get a  short-lived one with out user interaction?